# Allowing iframes to have independent document mode when Base page in IE9 document mode

Tags: iframe, internet-explorer-9, x-ua-compatible

Our application is designed in a way where we have a simple base page in which we have several iFrames that load different applications. This entire setup is loaded inside a WPF shell which hosts a web browser control.

I understand that the webbrowser control defaults to IE7 document mode by default. Some of the applications loaded in the iframe need to move up to IE9 standard. The idea was to update the base page  with  in order for the applications inside the iFrames to be rendered in IE9 mode.

The problem now is that, all iFrames are automatically moved up to IE9 mode and hence causing other incompatible applications to fail with JS/CSS issues.

Is there a way to get applications in certain iframes alone to move up to IE9 while others have time to  in future.

Answer (score 0):

You can change Browser Mode only for page, so you change all iFrames. By the way Browser Mode have changed manually, page will refresh and iFrames refresh too.

You must search for solution which all iFrames open correctly with same Browser Mode.